# Web scraping with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to do web scraping to the following webpage with rvest:
https://www.superu.ad/oli-de-girasol_c360259/

But it seems that rvest (R) is not capable to find some css selectors that already exists in the url, like `.product-name`

```
webpage<-read_html('https://www.superu.ad/oli-de-girasol_c360259/')
rank_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.product-name') #returns nothing
```

I expect the output of the different product names that appear in the url, but the actual output is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job :

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr) # to use the pipes %>%
webpage = read_html('https://www.superu.ad/oli-de-girasol_c360259/')
product_names = webpage %>% 
html_nodes(xpath= '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "product-name", " " ))]') %>%
html_text()

product_names
```

You should use Xpath with rvest, it works better than CSS selectors.

To get Xpath, you can use SelectorGadget extension for Chrome (you can switch to Xpath).

Comment: Could you explain why xpath works better than css selectors? In this case I think maybe due to the content-type application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8, but more generally is this really the case?

Comment: To be honest I dont know why, it is just by experience when using rvest. Maybe it is because you have to use a # character first in your css selector. Have a look here : https://stat4701.github.io/edav/2015/04/02/rvest_tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I experimented in python and found that it depended on the parser. If I used lxml it failed. It I used html.parser it worked. This often happens when a document is not perfectly-formed. Different parser == different result. Some elements end up being ignored for example.

To confirm this I put the url into

https://validator.w3.org/

i.e.

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.superu.ad%2Foli-de-girasol_c360259%2F

There are a number of errors with this page which might be implicated.

Perhaps this is of some use to you? Unsure what options you have for different parsers/packages that might better handle this situation|be more forgiving.

Example with python (apologies)

Works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.superu.ad/oli-de-girasol_c360259/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
products = [item.text for item in soup.select('.product-name')]
print(products)
```

Fails

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.superu.ad/oli-de-girasol_c360259/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
products = [item.text for item in soup.select('.product-name')]
print(products)
```